# CV2 not working even though its downloaded

Tags: python, macos, opencv, module

I am a beginner to programming and so as I was following a tutorial I had to download opencv-python. So I followed all the steps and downloaded it.

```
opencv-python 4.3.0.38
```

That is what is displayed on my terminal(mac) when I check to see if opencv is installed or not using the command `pip list | grep opencv`

So I write a test code(on pycharm)

```
import cv2
print('Code Completed')
```

it works fine and prints out `Code Completed`, but when I run the same code on terminal(I am on the correct directory) using the command `python Face_Detector.py` it displays an error message saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Face_Detector.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

**How do I resolve this issue?**
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you echo your PYTHONPATH variable and check if the path where opencv is installed on your computer is provided to the python interpreter. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Aravind, thanks for your help. Is there any way you could tell me how to do the things you have suggested

Answer (score 0):

run this in the terminal where you work this will add the path and directory directly to the terminal you are using maybe it's happening because of the environment path
**pip install opencv-python**

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you so much